# Python Error 10057 - Users unable to join, client hangs on loading

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, client

client

[image]

server

[image]

Any ideas? No user can can connect to the server as the client application just hangs on "loading"

Comment: You should show the code snippet that produced the error. Btw, you have a pretty specific error message on the server. You are changing the dict you are iterating on.

Comment: The whitelist is temporary, ids are written to it when player joins, but when the player leaves the ids are removed. Problem is, something is causing it to not write any ID down and when you copy and paste the ids from a backup in there, they are all deleted.
    
    `#Clear whitelist from expired entries
    for id in whitelist.keys():
        if (absNow - whitelist[id]["time"]) > expireTime:
            print("Deleting "+whitelist[id]["name"]+"...")
            remove[id] = whitelist[id]["name"]
    for id in remove.keys():
        del whitelist[id]`

Comment: `def commit_changes():
    global whitelist
    global remove
    threading.Timer(expireTime, commit_changes).start()
    absNow = int(mktime(localtime()))
    now = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime())`

So the issue is in the communication between the client and the server. The client hangs on "loading". When I remove line 66-72 (#Clear whitelist from expired entries) then users are able to connect as their ids are written down and removed. However the client is still stuck on loading :/ It's driving me crazy.